# Any Short code Availble for Get Post List With Thumbnail Plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, post-thumbnails, shortcode

Any Short code Availble for **[Get Post List With Thumbnail](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-post-list-with-thumbnails/)** Plugin? or else how to Create Short code for this Particular plugin?
Thank u in Advance.

Comment: Get Post List With Thumbnail Plugin is a widget which has option panel its not a quick fix to make it a shortcode.

Comment: absolutely you are correct Bainternet,but i want to develop this plugin by Adding Shortcode.We need to Use this Plugin Under Any Post or Any Page means we need to create shortcode..It Would be Great.Isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a quick crack at making it a shortcode paste this code in your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_shortcode('gplt','getPostListThumbs_shortcode');
function getPostListThumbs_shortcode($atts, $content = null){

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'orient' => 'v',
        'imgo' => false,
        'ttgo' => false,
        'dtgo' => false,
        'dtfrm' => 1,
        'categ' => '',
        'postnr' => 20,
        'linn' => 3,
        'tbwid' => 40,
        'tbhig' => 40       
    ), $atts));
    $orient = gtpartrat($orient,'v');
    $imgo = gtpartrat($imgo,false);
    $ttgo = gtpartrat($ttgo,false);
    $dtgo = gtpartrat($dtgo,false);
    $dtfrm = gtpartrat($dtfrm,1);
    $categ = gtpartrat($categ,'');
    $postnr = gtpartrat($postnr,20);
    $linn = gtpartrat($linn,3);
    $tbwid = gtpartrat($tbwid,40);
    $tbhig = gtpartrat($tbhig,40);

    $htmlcod = "<table id='div_postlist' width='".$divwid."' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='4'>"."\n";
    $htmlcod .= "<tr>"."\n";
    //
    if (have_posts()) :
        global $post;

        if($categ!=''){
            $strquery = "numberposts=".$postnr."&category_name=". $categ;
        }
        else{
              $strquery =  "numberposts=".$postnr;
        }

        $myposts=get_posts($strquery);

        $ctxtr = 0;
        switch($dtfrm){
            case 1:
                $dtdis = 'd/m/y';
            break;
            case 2:
                $dtdis = 'm/d/y';
            break;
        }
        if($myposts):

        foreach($myposts as $post) :

                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'numberposts' => -1,
                        'post_status' => null,
                        'post_parent' => $post->ID
                    );
                    $attachments = get_posts($args);


                    $imgsrc = "";
                    if ($attachments):

                        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

                            $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, array($tbwid,$tbhig), $icon = false);
                            break;
                        }
                    endif;

                    if($orient=="v"){     
                            if($ctxtr == 0){
                                $htmlcod .= "<tr>"."\n";
                            } 
                            $ctxtr = $ctxtr + 1;

                                $htmlcod .= "<td valign='top'>"."\n";
                            if($imgsrc!=""):                           
                                $htmlcod .= "<a href='". get_permalink() ."' title='". get_the_title() ."'>"."\n";
                                $htmlcod .= $imgsrc;
                                $htmlcod .= "</a>"."\n";                           
                            endif;
                                $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";

                            if(!$imgo){           
                                $htmlcod .= "<td valign='top'>"."\n";
                                if($dtgo):
                                $htmlcod .= "<p>".get_the_time($dtdis)."</p>";
                                endif;
                                if($ttgo):
                                $htmlcod .= "<a href='". get_permalink()."' title='". get_the_title() ."'>";
                                $htmlcod .= get_the_title();
                                $htmlcod .= "</a>"."\n";
                                endif;
                                $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";
                            }
                            $htmlcod .= "</tr><tr>"."\n";  
                    }
                    else{

                            if($ctxtr == 0){
                                $htmlcod .= "<tr>"."\n";
                            }      
                            $ctxtr = $ctxtr + 1;                      
                            $htmlcod .= "<td valign='top'>"."\n";
                            $htmlcod .= "<table cellpadding='3' cellspacing='3' border='0' width='100%'>"."\n";

                                $htmlcod .= "<tr>"."\n";
                                $htmlcod .= "<td valign='top'>"."\n";
                            if($imgsrc!=""):                           
                                $htmlcod .= "<a href='". get_permalink() ."' title='". get_the_title() ."'>"."\n";
                                $htmlcod .= $imgsrc;
                                $htmlcod .= "</a>"."\n";    
                                $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";                       
                            endif;

                            if(!$imgo){  
                                $htmlcod .= "<td valign='top'>"."\n";             
                                if($dtgo):
                                $htmlcod .= "<p>".get_the_time($dtdis)."</p>";
                                endif;
                                if($ttgo):
                                $htmlcod .= "<a href='". get_permalink()."' title='". get_the_title() ."'>";
                                $htmlcod .= get_the_title();
                                $htmlcod .= "</a>"."\n";
                                endif;      
                                $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";                         
                            }
                            $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";
                            $htmlcod .= "</tr>"."\n";
                            $htmlcod .= "</table>"."\n";
                            $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";
                            if($ctxtr == $linn){
                                $htmlcod .= "</tr>"."\n";
                                $ctxtr = 0;
                            }
                    }
        endforeach;
        else:
            $htmlcod = "<tr>"."\n";
            $htmlcod = "<td>"."\n";
            $htmlcod .= "No registers found."."\n";
            $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";
            $htmlcod .= "</tr>"."\n";
        endif;
    endif;
        $htmlcod .= "</table>";
    return $htmlcod;
}
```

**Usage:**

simply call the shortcode `[gplt parametes]` from any post or a page

**parameters:**

- Orientation: **orient="v"** // v =
  Vertical , h = Horizontal  default
  'v'
- Display only images: **imgo="false"** //
  true, false  default 'false'
- Display post title: **ttgo="false"** //
  true, false  default 'false'
- Display post date: **dtgo="false"** //
  true, false  default 'false'
- Date Format: **dtfrm="1"** // 1 - d/m/y ,
  2 - m/d/y  default '1'
- Category Name: **categ=''** // leave out
  or blank for all categories default
  ''
- Number of Posts: **postnr="20"**
  //default=20
- Number of registers per line:
  **linn="3"**  //default=3 only for
  horizontal orientation
- Thumbnails Width: **tbwid="40"**
  //default = 40
- Thumbnails Height: **tbhig="40"**
  //default = 40

Comment: Thank you Very Much Bainternet.Really Amazing performance done by you.But Still Am not Getting This Plugin in My Page.I added Your code in functions.php and Activate the Plugin.Then i Create a Short code like  [gplt orient="v",imgo="true",ttgo="false",dtgo="false",categ='',postnr="100",tbwid="130",tbhig="75"] under a New Page.where i had done Mistake?

Comment: Replace the comma with spaces between each parameter

Comment: am changed my code to [gplt orient="v" imgo="true" ttgo="false" dtgo="false" categ='' postnr="100" tbwid="130" tbhig="75"].but still it's not working.i got an Empty Page only & No Error's are Shown.

Comment: What are the errors

Comment: please Solve My Problem.may you help me @Bainternet?

Comment: Now it's Working but 87 times show the same plugin.Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a new version for [Get Post List With Thumbnails 4.0.0](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-post-list-with-thumbnails/) and now it's possible to use shortcodes.

Comment: Wow,Great work.Welcome to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/. i give it works in wordpress.org. Try to add useful plugin like this.:) keep rocking..

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Shortcode for Get Recent Post Thumbnail
add_shortcode('gplt','getPostListThumbs_shortcode');
```

function getPostListThumbs_shortcode($atts, $content = null){

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'orient' => 'v',
    'imgo' => true,
    'ttgo' => true,
    'dtgo' => false,
    'dtfrm' => 1,
    'categ' => '',
    'postnr' => 500,
    'linn' => 3,
    'tbwid' => 175,
    'tbhig' => 100       
), $atts));
$orient = gtpartrat($orient,'v');
$imgo = gtpartrat($imgo,false);
$ttgo = gtpartrat($ttgo,false);
$dtgo = gtpartrat($dtgo,false);
$dtfrm = gtpartrat($dtfrm,1);
$categ = gtpartrat($categ,'');
$postnr = gtpartrat($postnr,500);
$linn = gtpartrat($linn,3);
$tbwid = gtpartrat($tbwid,175);
$tbhig = gtpartrat($tbhig,100);

$htmlcod = "<table id='div_postlist' width='".$divwid."' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='4'>"."\n";
$htmlcod .= "<tr>"."\n";
//
```

// if (have_posts()) :
        global $post;

```
    if($categ!=''){
        $strquery = "numberposts=".$postnr."&category_name=". $categ;
    }
    else{
          $strquery =  "numberposts=".$postnr;
    }

    $myposts=get_posts($strquery);

    $ctxtr = 0;
    switch($dtfrm){
        case 1:
            $dtdis = 'd/m/y';
        break;
        case 2:
            $dtdis = 'm/d/y';
        break;
    }
    if($myposts):

    foreach($myposts as $post) :

                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_status' => null,
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID
                );
                $attachments = get_posts($args);


                $imgsrc = "";
                if ($attachments):

                    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

                        $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, array($tbwid,$tbhig), $icon = false);
                        break;
                    }
                endif;

                if($orient=="v"){     
                        if($ctxtr == 0){
                            $htmlcod .= "<tr>"."\n";
                        } 
                        $ctxtr = $ctxtr + 1;

                            $htmlcod .= "<td valign='top'>"."\n";
                        if($imgsrc!=""):                           
                            $htmlcod .= "<a href='". get_permalink() ."' title='". get_the_title() ."'>"."\n";
                            $htmlcod .= $imgsrc;
                            $htmlcod .= "</a>"."\n";                           
                        endif;
                            $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";

                        if(!$imgo){           
                            $htmlcod .= "<td valign='top'>"."\n";
                            if($dtgo):
                            $htmlcod .= "<p>".get_the_time($dtdis)."</p>";
                            endif;
                            if($ttgo):
                            $htmlcod .= "<a href='". get_permalink()."' title='". get_the_title() ."'>";
                            $htmlcod .= get_the_title();
                            $htmlcod .= "</a>"."\n";
                            endif;
                            $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";
                        }
                        $htmlcod .= "</tr><tr>"."\n";  
                }
                else{

                        if($ctxtr == 0){
                            $htmlcod .= "<tr>"."\n";
                        }      
                        $ctxtr = $ctxtr + 1;                      
                        $htmlcod .= "<td valign='top'>"."\n";
                        $htmlcod .= "<table cellpadding='3' cellspacing='3' border='0' width='100%'>"."\n";

                            $htmlcod .= "<tr>"."\n";
                            $htmlcod .= "<td valign='top'>"."\n";
                        if($imgsrc!=""):                           
                            $htmlcod .= "<a href='". get_permalink() ."' title='". get_the_title() ."'>"."\n";
                            $htmlcod .= $imgsrc;
                            $htmlcod .= "</a>"."\n";    
                            $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";                       
                        endif;

                        if(!$imgo){  
                            $htmlcod .= "<td valign='top'>"."\n";             
                            if($dtgo):
                            $htmlcod .= "<p>".get_the_time($dtdis)."</p>";
                            endif;
                            if($ttgo):
                            $htmlcod .= "<a href='". get_permalink()."' title='". get_the_title() ."'>";
                            $htmlcod .= get_the_title();
                            $htmlcod .= "</a>"."\n";
                            endif;      
                            $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";                         
                        }
                        $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";
                        $htmlcod .= "</tr>"."\n";
                        $htmlcod .= "</table>"."\n";
                        $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";
                        if($ctxtr == $linn){
                            $htmlcod .= "</tr>"."\n";
                            $ctxtr = 0;
                        }
                }
    endforeach;
    else:
        $htmlcod = "<tr>"."\n";
        $htmlcod = "<td>"."\n";
        $htmlcod .= "No registers found."."\n";
        $htmlcod .= "</td>"."\n";
        $htmlcod .= "</tr>"."\n";
    endif;
// endif;
    $htmlcod .= "</table>";
return $htmlcod;
```

} 
i Found the bug in  this line 'if (have_posts()) :' .We Need to make Comment  Lines. 
1.//if (have_posts()) : 
2. // endif;
Now It's Working Fine.Hurrahhhhh.Thanks Bainternet :)